# tomcat errors in idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

when i run my code with Tomcat in idea.i run with the following error.i know there is some wrong about the configuration about Tomcat.But i do not how to find it.

```
[2018-12-05 09:01:14,894] Artifact SSMCRUD:Web exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:336)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:786)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5212)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resource
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1163)
        ... 56 more
```

the following is my pom.

```
    <groupId>com.dxq</groupId>
    <artifactId>SSM-CRUD</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- 引入项目依赖的jar包-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--面向切面的编程-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mybatis整合spring的适配包 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>2.5-20081211</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

what is wrong about my code? Is there some wrongs about the configuration in my pom.xml

Comment: Check that the artifact includes all the required dependencies: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the following is my dependencies.i can not find any wrong!